# fine grained access control for action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let us say we have an action method like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(int a, int b)
```

In order to implement some fine grained authorization one could implement an action that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute and accesses the parameters above using:

```
filterContext.RouteData.Values
```

during OnActionExecuting. Is this good practice? Are there better approaches for such fine grained authorizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this good practice?

Of course that it is a security risk. Relying on parameters that could be sent by the client is dangerous. Remember that the client can send you whatever he wants values as parameters. And whether you implement filters, actions, binders or whatever on the server, your security is compromised. Never rely on parameters sent by the client to implement any security.

But if you want to implement some security checks, those checks should absolutely be done in a custom `IAuthorizationFilter`, not in action filters. Authorization filters run much earlier in the execution pipeline than action filters.

For example:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // no authenticated user => no need to go any further
            return false;
        }

        var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        // get the username of the currently authentciated user
        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // Get the a parameter
        string a = routeData.Values["a"] as string;

        // Get the b parameter
        string b = routeData.Values["b"] as string;

        return IsAuthorized(username, a, b);
    }

    private bool IsAuthorized(string username, string a, string b)
    {
        // TODO: you know what to do here => hit the database to check
        // whether the user is authorized to work with a and b
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good points. The scenario is that I will have to check whether user owns item given some id(s). This will require some database interaction. Maybe it is better to move this further to the backend and throw an exception which is caught by an ExceptionFilter.

Comment: Also would you use filterContext.RouteData.Values to access id(s) values? or are there neater methods?

Comment: Fair enough. A perfectly valid scenario for an authorization filter (derive from AuthorizeAttribute and override the AuthorizeCore method). You should use the currently logged in user from the HttpContext and then use  filterContext.RouteData.Values to access the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, if this is a security check, it would be recommended to implement an `IAuthorizationFilter`, instead of waiting for OnActionExecuting, which is way later in the request.